# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist during form validation

Tags: django

I have an issue that makes me crazy

I have model

```
class Property1(CommonInfo):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    is_true = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    propertytype = models.ForeignKey(Propertytype, related_name='propertytype')
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    followup_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.propertytype

    def clean(self):
        model = self.__class__
        if  (self.unit) and model.objects.filter(unit=self.unit, propertytype=self.propertytype ).exclude(id=self.id).count() == 1:
            raise ValidationError('Same property cant be assigned more then ones')
```

for this model I have form

```
class Property1Form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Property1
        fields = ['unit','propertytype','is_true','date','followup_date','quantity','description']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Property1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance:
            self.fields['unit'].required = False
            self.fields['unit'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
```

And I have a view

```
def property_new(request,pk,uri):
    unit = get_object_or_404(Unit, pk=pk)
    title = 'property'
    uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Property1Form(request.POST)
        form.unit = unit


        if form.is_valid():
            properties = form.save(commit=False)
            properties.unit = unit 

            properties.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, str(properties.unit) + "-SUCCESS Object created sucssefully")

            return redirect(uri)
    else:
        form = Property1Form(initial={'unit': unit})


    return render(request, 'object_edit.html', {'form': form, 'title':title, 'extend': EXTEND})
```

However, after creating new property I always get

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at *** Property1 has no unit.

Error triggered during execution of

```
  if form.is_valid():
```

What is the problem?

UPDATE:

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\rentout\unit\views.py" in property_new
  390.         if form.is_valid():
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  184.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  176.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  394.         self._post_clean()
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  430.             self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in full_clean
  1132.             self.clean()
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\rentout\unit\models.py" in clean
  117.         if  (self.unit) and model.objects.filter(unit=self.unit, propertytype=self.propertytype ).exclude(id=self.id).count() == 1:
File "C:\Users\Boris\dev\rentout\virtrentout\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in __get__
  608.                 "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /unit/property/new/6/http://127.0.0.1:8000/unit/property_details/6/
Exception Value: Property1 has no unit.
```

Comment: form.unit = unit  is not doing what you want.

Try to assign this value to the object. not to the form.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Try changing `if (self.unit)` to `if self.unit_id`.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you it did help. Why it is happening?

Comment: @Zartch it does work some time . But I dont really understand why it is not consistent. However if I am creating a new object i dont have an object yet .

Comment: Sometimes unit is not required. "self.fields['unit'].required = False." 
Maybe assign the unit like: "form.fields['unit'] = unit"  (Don't know if this coud work)

Answer (score 1):

Setting `required=False` and disabling the widget is not ideal. Disabling the widget means that your browser will not submit any values for that field. Since you have `required=False`, this means that the form will set the foreign key to `None`. However, this is incompatible with the model's foreign key, which has `null=False` by default.

I'm not familiar enough with the internals to precisely explain the exception, but the basic problem is that Django is trying to fetch the related `unit` from the database, after the form has set the foreign key to `None`.

One work around is to check `self.unit_id` rather than `self.unit`. This prevents the database lookup, so you don't get the exception.

However, this seems a bit dirty to me. If you don't want the user to edit the `unit` field, I would remove it from the form completely. Check `self.instance.pk` to determine whether or not the instance is in the database already.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Property1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.pk:
        del self.fields['unit']
```

Then in your view, you shouldn't have to set `properties.unit = unit` any more. I would remove `form.unit = unit` as well, I don't think it was ever useful.