# Why clean method in my form will not clean?

Tags: django, django-forms

I wrote a clean method on my form and it is not actually doing the validation.

```
class Property1Form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Property1
        fields = ['unit','propertytype','is_true','date','followup_date','quantity','description']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Property1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance:
            self.fields['unit'].required = False
            self.fields['unit'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'

    def clean(self):
        form_data = self.cleaned_data
        if  Property1.objects.filter(unit=form_data['unit'], propertytype=form_data['propertytype'] ).count() > 0:
            self._errors["propertytype"] = ["Propertytype already exists for unit"] # Will raise a error message
            del form_data['propertytype']
```

Same validation does work for me on model level but on model level I am getting 500 error

> ValidationError at
>   /unit/property/new/6/http://127.0.0.1:8000/unit/property_details/6/
>   {'**all**': [u'Same property cant be assigned more then ones']}

So trying to have same validation on the form side as well.

UPDATE:

view method

```
def property_new(request,pk,uri):
    unit = get_object_or_404(Unit, pk=pk)
    title = 'property'
    uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Property1Form(request.POST)
        form.fields['unit'] = unit


        if form.is_valid():
            properties = form.save(commit=False)
            properties.unit = unit 

            properties.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, str(properties.unit) + "-SUCCESS Object created sucssefully")

            return redirect(uri)
    else:
        form = Property1Form(initial={'unit': unit})



    return render(request, 'object_edit.html', {'form': form, 'title':title, 'extend': EXTEND})
```

Comment: add your view code, and tracelog of error

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev updated with the view code. I am not getting an error so no trace log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `required=False` and disabled the `unit` field. That means that the browser will not submit any values for the `unit` field.

Therefore `form.cleaned_data['unit']` is `None`, so the `if` statement in your `clean` method is always `False`.

As I suggested on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379990/relatedobjectdoesnotexist-during-form-validation), I think it's a bad idea to set `required=False` and disabled the `unit` field. If you don't want the user to edit the field, don't include it in the form.